# how to conver multi level json data to C# Object?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I know there are several problem with json but nothing as same as to me. My problem
How to convert this jsonString to c# object. I've tried several time. This unexpected problem made me frustrated. I need to know whats problem with me and what should i do....

{
    "status": 200,
    "status_messages": "Success ",
    "data": [
        {
            "Alarm And Alert": [
                {
                    "0": "1",
                    "1": "Alarm And Alert 1",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Alarm And Alert 1",
                    "islock": "0"
                },
                {
                    "0": "6",
                    "1": "Alarm And Alert 6",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "6",
                    "name": "Alarm And Alert 6",
                    "islock": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Animal": [
                {
                    "0": "7",
                    "1": "Bird",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "7",
                    "name": "Bird",
                    "islock": "0"
                },
                {
                    "0": "13",
                    "1": "Funny Animals",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "13",
                    "name": "Funny Animals",
                    "islock": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Dj": [
                {
                    "0": "14",
                    "1": "Dj 1",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "14",
                    "name": "Dj 1",
                    "islock": "0"
                },
                {
                    "0": "15",
                    "1": "Dj 2",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "15",
                    "name": "Dj 2",
                    "islock": "0"
                },
                {
                    "0": "18",
                    "1": "Dj 5",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "18",
                    "name": "Dj 5",
                    "islock": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Rap": [
                {
                    "0": "71",
                    "1": "Rap Ringtones 1",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "71",
                    "name": "Rap Ringtones 1",
                    "islock": "0"
                },
                {
                    "0": "77",
                    "1": "Rap Ringtones 7",
                    "2": "0",
                    "id": "77",
                    "name": "Rap Ringtones 7",
                    "islock": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

My Classs:

```
public  class Category
    {
        public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
        public string islock { get; set; }
    }

public  class CategoryCollection
    {
      public List<Category> CategoryRingtone { get; set; }
    }

public  class RootObject
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public string status_messages { get; set; }
        public List<CategoryCollection> data { get; set; }
    }

categoriesJsonString = await Downloader.LoadCategoriesFromServer();
            RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(categoriesJsonString));
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(rootObject.GetType());
            rootObject = ser.ReadObject(ms) as RootObject;
            ms.Close();
```

Comment: copy & pasting your json on http://jsonlint.org/ shows that it is invalid. a good start would be to use valid json. it would also help if you say what problem you actually have. what is the "unexpected problem"?

Comment: I've edited my json as valid, Actually i made concise jsonString to be shorter to read easily. Thanks

Comment: now, if you could just say what this mysterious "unexpected problem" actually is, someone might actually help you. is the"CategoryRingtone" List always empty? does it give you errors? which? or what?

Comment: Yes thats the problem. "CategoryRingtone" List always empty.

Comment: Thanks to all who are extended your hand to help me. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlarmAndAlert
{
    public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string islock { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string islock { get; set; }
}

public class Dj
{
    public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string islock { get; set; }
}

public class Rap
{
    public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string islock { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public List<AlarmAndAlert> __invalid_name__Alarm And Alert { get; set; }
    public List<Animal> Animal { get; set; }
    public List<Dj> Dj { get; set; }
    public List<Rap> Rap { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string status_messages { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```